# github actions, How to use pkg to package node projects containing sqlite3 across platforms

Tags: node.js, sqlite

I try to download node_sqlite3.node and copy to node_modules/sqlite3/lib/binding/, but i can't find `lib/binding/node-v83-linux-x64/node_sqlite3.node`

Is there a better way?

this is my ci file
`name: Build and push Docker image

on:
push:
branches: [main]

jobs:
build:
strategy:
matrix:
os: [ubuntu-latest, windows-latest, macos-latest]
architecture: [x64, arm64]
node-version: [16]
pkg-target: [host]

```
runs-on: ${{ matrix.os }}
permissions: write-all

steps:
  - name: Set up Node.js
    uses: actions/setup-node@v2
    with:
      node-version: ${{ matrix.node-version }}
      architecture: ${{ matrix.architecture }}

  - name: Checkout code
    uses: actions/checkout@v2

  - name: Npm Install
    run: |
      npm install -g pkg
      npm install --build-from-source

  - name: Build Release
    run: pkg . --target ${{ matrix.pkg-target }}

  - name: release
    uses: softprops/action-gh-release@v1
    if: startsWith(github.ref, 'refs/tags/')
    with:
      files: "dist/**"
    env:
      GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.TOKEN }}
```

`